# How to match multiple input values in a switch case statement?

Tags: java, switch-statement

What piece of code do I need to make it so that if the user enters 7, 8, or 9 dogs; it will still output the message in case 6?

```
int dogs;

dogs = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many dogs do you have?"));

switch (dogs)
{
           ...
           ...
           ...
case 4: JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Four dogs is too many."); break;

case 5: JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Five dogs means you're a crazy person."); break;

case 6: JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"That is totally unbelieveable.");

default: JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Invalid input.");

} // end switch
```

Comment: Add cases for those that flow into 6 and break.

Comment: What about 1, 2, 3 dogs? And 0?

Comment: Look up "switch fallthrough"

Comment: 6 or more? like 6 to one milion? that cant be done with switch in java, you need to add an separate if for that

Comment: A map is better suited here than a switch.

Comment: I suggest making case 6 your default case, but then you need to perform an if check for negative dogs.

Answer (score 4):

Check for an invalid number, then just use a `default` clause:

```
if (dogs < 0) {
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Invalid input.");
} else {
  switch(dogs) {
    // ...
  case 5: 
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Five dogs means you're a crazy person.");
    break;
  default:
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"That is totally unbelieveable.");
    break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
case 6:
case 7:
case 8:
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"That is totally unbelieveable.");
  break;
```

This will do the job.

However I'd change it to:

```
case 4: JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Four dogs is too many."); break;
case 5: JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Five dogs means you're a crazy person."); break;
default:  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"That is totally unbelieveable.");break;
```

This will eliminate the Invalid Output message, but will work for each and every number > 5, but i think that is acceptable, since the value of dogs comes out from an `Integer.parseInt()` call. If content is invalid an exceptin will be thrown there, and the Invalid Input message can be showed inside the exception handler and like wise an exception can be thrown if dogs is negative.

This has the advantage that will work for every number of dogs. If in need to manage a different error message, it will be enough just add the specific `case` branch.

```
int dogs;

try {
     dogs = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many dogs do you have?"));
     if (dogs < 0) {
         throw new Exception("Negative dog is impossible!");
     }
    switch (dogs)
    {
           ...
           ...
           ...
    case 4: JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Four dogs is too many."); break;

    case 5: JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Five dogs means you're a crazy person."); break;

    default: JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"That is totally unbelieveable.");break;
    } 
} catch (Exception e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Invalid input.");
}
```

Comment: Agreed - put a single test for a negative (or otherwise invalid number) outside the switch statement and then use the default option as BigMike suggests.

Answer (score 3):

Simply add cases for 7,8,9 with 6

```
case 6: 
case 7:
case 8:
case 9:
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"That is totally unbelieveable."); 
break;
```

Comment: I mean I was just listing other numbers. What if the user keeps going? Like say entering 100 dogs. Isn't it inefficient to have 100 cases, even though I know after 6 or more dogs it will say the same message?

Comment: @DannyHsu Then there are two choices 1. Create individual case conditions for values less than 6 and let other numbers go to default 2. Use if else instead of switch

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;

public class DogCheck {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  int dogs;
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Enter Number of Dogs :");
  dogs=input.nextInt();
  if (dogs < 0)
      System.out.println("WoW! Aliens has arrived...")
  else 
  switch(dogs) {
  case 4: JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Four dogs is too many."); break;
  case 5: JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Five dogs means you're a crazy `person."); break;`
  default:
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"That is totally unbelieveable.");
    break;
  }
 }
}
```